# Add Multiple Submit Buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Im trying to create a form where a different image is displayed depending on the item selected via dropdown, I have completed this but now need to link each image to its product page (html) but not sure how?

```
<center>
<form name="mygallery"><p>
<select name="picture" size="1" onChange="showimage()">
<option selected value="images/products_lights/chandler_blue.jpg">Gem Light Blue</option>
<option value="images/products_lights/chandler_pink.jpg">Gem Light Pink</option>
<option value="images/products_lights/gem_white.jpg">Gem Light White</option>
<option value="images/products_lights/chandler_pink2.jpg">Chandelier Pink</option>
<option value="images/products_lights/chandler_white.jpg">Chandelier White</option>
<option value="images/products_lights/pod_black.jpg">Pod Light Black</option>
<option value="images/products_lights/pod_blue.jpg">Pod Light Blue</option>
<option value="images/products_lights/pod_gold.jpg">Pod Light Gold</option>
<option value="images/products_lights/pod_green.jpg">Pod Light Green</option>
<option value="images/products_lights/pod_red.jpg">Pod Light Red</option>
<option value="images/products_lights/pod_silver.jpg">Pod Light Silver</option>
<option value="images/products_lights/shade_black.jpg">Shade Black</option>
<option value="images/products_lights/shade_blue.jpg">Shade Blue</option>
</select>
</p>
</form>
</center>


<p align="center"><img src="images/products_lights/chandler_blue.jpg" name="pictures" width="90%" height="90%">
```

I thought of maybe adding a submit button but again not sure how to change the url it points to?...

Comment: add code of `showimage ` function

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to redirect based on the selection when the selection is made, therefore you would not need a button. Since you tagged jQuery, this should give you a start:

```
$('select').on('change',function() {
    window.location = 'http://example.com/' + $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The url is specified via the `action` attribute of the `<form>` tag. But you can also specify the url in the submit button code using the `formaction` attribute. Cant really help more because i dont know how your script looks.

But here is a Snippet that should help you :

```js
function showimage() {
  var selection = document.getElementById("picture").value;
  var url = selection.split("/");
  document.getElementById("pictures").src = selection;
  document.getElementById("send").formAction = "http://www.example.com/" + url[url.length - 1];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <center>
    <form name="mygallery">
      <select name="picture" id="picture" size="1" onChange="showimage()">
        <option selected value="images/products_lights/chandler_blue.jpg">Gem Light Blue</option>
        <option value="images/products_lights/chandler_pink.jpg">Gem Light Pink</option>
        <option value="images/products_lights/gem_white.jpg">Gem Light White</option>
        <option value="images/products_lights/chandler_pink2.jpg">Chandelier Pink</option>
        <option value="images/products_lights/chandler_white.jpg">Chandelier White</option>
        <option value="images/products_lights/pod_black.jpg">Pod Light Black</option>
        <option value="images/products_lights/pod_blue.jpg">Pod Light Blue</option>
        <option value="images/products_lights/pod_gold.jpg">Pod Light Gold</option>
        <option value="images/products_lights/pod_green.jpg">Pod Light Green</option>
        <option value="images/products_lights/pod_red.jpg">Pod Light Red</option>
        <option value="images/products_lights/pod_silver.jpg">Pod Light Silver</option>
        <option value="images/products_lights/shade_black.jpg">Shade Black</option>
        <option value="images/products_lights/shade_blue.jpg">Shade Blue</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" id="send" />
    </form>
  </center>
  <p align="center">
    <img src="images/products_lights/chandler_blue.jpg" name="pictures" id="pictures" width="90%" height="90%">
  </p>
  <script>
    showimage()
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `<option value="imageurl##producturl">Gem Light Blue</option>`
Then in `showimage(combinedurl)` you can split `var split_image_product_url = combinedurl.split('##');` and then easily use `split_image_product_url[0]` for image url and `split_image_product_url[1]` for product page URL.

Note this is just an Idea there can be multiple ways to achieve the same using hidden field values and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute `data-url` to each option that contains the url of the product, look at that code sample.

```js
function changeProduct(selectNode){
  $option_selected = $(selectNode).find(':selected'); 
  $prod_link = $('#product');
  $prod_link.attr('href', $option_selected.attr('data-url'));
  $prod_link.find('img').attr('src', $option_selected.val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="changeProduct(this)">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select a product</option>
  <option value="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/tree_of_light_wallpaper_landscape_nature_wallpaper_1210.jpg" data-url="www.google.com">Product 1</option>
  <option value="http://blog-imgs-52.fc2.com/l/a/n/landscape928/Landscape-Wallpapers.jpg" data-url="www.stackoverflow.com">Product 2</option>
</select><br><br>

<a href="about:blank" id="product"><img src="http://frankfortecig.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/placeholder-Copy-2.gif" alt="product" ></a>
```